# Specific value from database of mongoldb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been trying to get the specific value from database of MongoDB in node.js using. I have used find() and findOne() but in both case I am getting some object like thing in console.
This is my code:

```
const mongos=require('mongoose')
const { default: mongoose } = require('mongoose')
mongos.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/chat")
const upSchema=mongos.Schema({
    user:String,
    password:Number,
    email:String
})
const chat_up =mongos.model('up',upSchema)

let userName=req.body.user
    let pass=req.body.pass
    let name=chat_up.findOne({"user":userName,"password":pass})
    console.log(name)
```

This is my database:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("624057512a4c11d61e4a8226"), "user" : "Ashutosh", "password" : 12345, "email" : "seulij@sids.conm", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62407c03f1c4d198344907a7"), "user" : "wertgsdfbsrthfx", "password" : 1234345, "email" : "gfsdf@sdfg.com", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62407c1ff1c4d198344907a9"), "user" : "", "password" : null, "email" : "", "__v" : 0 }
```

How can I get only value of "user" like "Ashutosh" using query in my console.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [project](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) the field:

```
db.collection.find({
 "user": "Ashutosh"
},
{
 user: 1,
 _id: 0
})
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8QaH4PxyLog)

Answer (score 1):

in order to print the username you just need:

```
console.log(name.user)
```